# Game freezes but PC keeps running, which component may be the cause?

Tags: freeze, desktop-computer

Which component(s) are most likely the problem when my PC keeps crashing with the following symptoms:

- During gaming every now and then my PC freezes
- The frequency of that happening ranges between twice per evening to once per week.
- Mid-game suddenly the screen freezes and the sound stops.
- The fans keeps running, I still hear the harddisk making noise and the display still shows the frame that was shown when the game froze.
- The only thing I can do is hold the power off button of my PC to turn the PC off, the PC doesn't respond to any other input from the keyboard or mouse.
- The windows event log doesnt show any events not does the reliability center.
- The issue has been happening for a long time now (half a year orso).
- It happens only while gaming, but for multiple different games (also older games that arent very heavy to run).
- I've already tried updating drivers, firmware and software.
- When [image: I run Speedfan to monitor tempe]ratures during a gaming session all temperatures seem fine, except it shows a fire icon on the GPU which looks bad but the temperature shows only 62 celsius which i think isnt high right? (see image)

Does this sound like a PSU problem, a motherboard problem, a GPU problem, a CPU problem or could it be any one of those?

Comment: What is your graphics card, if any?

Comment: 62C for a GPU is nowhere near the thermal limits for Nvidia and AMD products nor is it the thermal limits of Intel's iGPU

Comment: my graphics card is: MSI Videokaart PCI-e GeForce GTX560 Ti Twin Frozr II OC 1GB 2xDVI

Answer (score 0):

It is because of dust or moisture in your RAM. Open the cabinet, remove RAM and wipe the gold plate with a clean cloth. It should fix the problem